# Нормально ли для си иметь такую структуру зависимости объектов?

Tags: c, struct

Структура:

```
typedef struct some_struct
{
    struct some_struct* p_next_link_self; // Где данный указатель
                                            // будет указывать на объект
                                            // который ссылается на него,
                                            // и в случае уничтожения текущего объекта,
                                            // цепочкой освободить все остальные объекты
    // далее идут поля и прочее
} some_struct_t;
```

Т.е. якобы реализация наполовину цепочного соединения, где структуры будут знать кто на них ссылается, и освобождать все это дело в обратном порядке или если это можно назвать ветвлением зависимостей.

Comment: Да, нормально. Обычный односвязный список, применяется чуть ли не в каждой программе.

Comment: даже трудно предположить, что здесь может смущать =)

Comment: @freim: Для "односвязного списка" указатель надо было бы объявлять как  `struct some_struct *`.

Comment: @LLENN: Типа `struct some_struct_t` у вас не объявлено вообще. О каком цепочечном соединении идет речь? Как `struct some_struct_t` относится к `struct some_struct`? Будьте внимательнее при составлении вопроса. Ваш код содержит опечатки, которые делают весь вопрос бессмысленным.

Comment: @AnT, очепятка же, очевидно...

Comment: Речь идет о том что при уничтожении корневого объекта, он потянет разрушение всех его потомков (кто использовал данный объект для инициализации других объектов).

Comment: @LLENN: Что значит "потянет"? В языке С ничего за собой ничего никогда само по себе не "тянет". Все вам самому надо делать своими руками. Вы пока что описали тривиальный процесс освобождения односвязного списка. А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: @LLENN думаю вам сначала следует почитать про
1) односвязный список
2) двусвязный список
3) деревья

Comment: Комментарий: "Где данный указатель будет указывать на объект, который ссылается на него" - это о чем речь вообще? Кто на кого ссылается?

Comment: @AnT: ну что же Вы сразу нападаете на человека?) Не могу ручаться со 100% уверенностью, но я все же почти уверен, что ТС это все прекрасно понимает и на деле вопрос звучит так: «Я продумал структуру, в которой каждый ее экземпляр ссылается на последующий. При уничтожении объекта я повлеку уничтожение всех связных объектов по цепочке. Нормальна ли такая реализация?»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё у Вас абсолютно нормально. Вот цитата из классики ("Язык программирования Си". Брайан В. Керниган, Деннис М. Ритчи
) :

> Вернемся к описанию узла, которое удобно представить в виде структуры
>   с четырьмя компонентами:

```
struct tnode {          /*  узел дерева */
    char *word;         /*  указатель на текст */
    int count;          /*  число вхождений */
    struct tnode *left; /* левый сын */
    struct tnode *right;/* правый сын */
};
```

> Приведенное рекурсивное определение узла может показаться рискованным,
>   но оно правильное. Структура не может включать саму себя, но ведь

```
struct tnode *left;
```

> объявляет *left* как указатель на *tnode*, а не сам *tnode*.